# How is the rotational energy of a black hole converted into a magnetic field used to power relativistic jets?

Tags: electromagnetism, black-holes, magnetic-fields, electric-circuits, relativistic-jets

When an electric charge is lowered into a nonrotating black hole it will ["spread" itself across the surface](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/542873/why-are-fieldlines-getting-distorted-near-a-conducting-sphere), and the surface will behave like an electrical conductor. Why does this spread occur?

A spinning black hole behaves like a spinning conductor. Suppose that the gas approaching a spinning black hole contains a magnetic field. Apperently the resulting spinning conductor (black hole) in a magnetic field (gas) behaves like a ["unipolar inductor"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/542489/what-is-a-unipolar-inductor). Using the magnetic field as a conductor, a circuit will form, with a voltage difference between the equator and the poles. This "black hole battery" will also, regardless of its mass, have a resistance of about 100 Ohms. How come? (More on this here: https://1lib.eu/book/2339827/854387 [pages 157, 158, 159])

PS: I know there is a very similar question form four years ago, but as it hasnt yet been answered, I thought I`d ask it again. I apologize in advance for this rollercoaster of a question, please understand that it is my first.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/416413/what-happens-when-an-electric-charge-crosses-the-event-horizon/416449#416449

Comment: I`ve done some research on this since I asked this question, which is summarized in [this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/40624/why-are-relativistic-jets-perpendicular-to-the-accretion-disk/40918#40918) i gave to a related question. I do still have some questions left, like: Why does the electric charge spread itself across the surface of the black hole when it is falling towards it?

Comment: A Schwarzschild black hole horizon, as observed from outside, has a finite area, but a zero volume while the radius depends on how it is defined. In the original solution by Karl Schwarzschild, the radius of the horizon is zero, so a falling charge just hits the entire horizon at $r=0$.